# passing integer with leading zeroes to a function in golang

Tags: go

Please refer to my code below for understanding the problem I am describing.

When I pass 23, the function printMe, it prints 23, whereas if I pass 023 (which is also 23) - it prints 19.

What is the reason for this behavior? Only clue I have so far, is that this looks like the octal value 23 (octal) -> 19 (decimal).

Thanks in advance.

https://play.golang.org/p/Zrkq04Nu2DV

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    printMe(23)
    printMe(023)
}

func printMe(num int) {
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", num)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed the octal value, you can read more about it [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_literals). To be more explicit which base should be used you could also use `0o23` instead of `023`

Answer (score 2):

If you look in the golang language specification, the section on [integer literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_literals) describes this behaviour. A leading `0` is treated as an octal number.